# Firefox not able to enumerate document.styleSheets[].cssRules[]

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, securityexception

Here is the code:

- http://jsfiddle.net/salman/2hyYg/
- http://jsfiddle.net/salman/2hyYg/show/

You'll notice the `alert(document.styleSheets[x].cssRules.length)` fails with a "security exception". Any workaround for this. I am asking because there are a couple of "CSS lazy loading" classes out there that use this feature to detect if the CSS document is loaded.

Also: is the security exception a correct behavior/does it conform to standards?

Comment: I am getting Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object"  code: "15" nsresult: "0x8053000f (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_ACCESS_ERR)"  location: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/salman/2hyYg/show/ Line: 49"] in the first example

Comment: `NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_ACCESS_ERR` is the error.

Comment: and
Error: width is null
Source File: http://jsfiddle.net/js/LayoutCM.js
Line: 189
in the second

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... I've revised the fiddle slightly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get that error when trying to read a stylesheet loaded from a different domain or server, or trying to read an  @import  rule.

For your purpose, just check the  document.styleSheets.length .

Comment: _For your purpose, just check the stylesheets.length, it won't increment until the stylesheet with all of it's rules has rendered in the browser._ << is this a tried and tested workaround?

Comment: Guess not... chrome does _not_ increment document.styleSheets.length until the stylesheet is loaded, but FireFox _does_. Did not check other browsers.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2013, you can set the "crossorigin" attribute on the <link>-Element to signal the browser that this CSS is trusted (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).

After that, you can access its rules via Javascript.

Comment: doesn't work in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You are loading css-files from another domain, I guess that you are not allowed to modify cssRules for externally loaded css files.

see this: [Accessing cross-domain style sheet with .cssRules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211536/accessing-cross-domain-stylesheet-with-cssrules)

Answer (score 1):

Try with condition: (IE workaround)

```
function aftermath(index) {
    var css = document.styleSheets[index].rules || document.styleSheets[index].cssRules;
    alert(css.length);
}
```

This is giving the error:

```
aftermath(document.styleSheets.length - 1);
```

If i set it to 0 all work fine...
The problem is that the css is not ready at this time, if you need to access 
it, you need to do that in a second moment

Last edit:

If you whant keep css updated from source, you can use a php proxy for loading it:

```
<?php
$name = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/$_GET[version]/themes/$_GET[theme]/jquery-ui.css';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

Then you can get it using e.g. `/proxy.php?version=1.7.0&theme=humanity`

Comment: I've revised the fiddle and added a delay. But I cannot get past the security issue no matter what I do.

Comment: As i say, after you set *window.setTimeout(aftermath, 2000);* all work fine... Except for the security error

Comment: Proxy is a valid option; not in my case though.

Comment: Ah, the advantages of a CDN, without any of the advantages of a CDN ;)

Answer (score 1):

The stylesheet is there and works fine, you just cannot access the `cssRules` property of the stylesheet because it is set to null by the browser.

The security error you get is due to the same origin policy - you are working on stylesheets from another domain, you will not have this problem if the stylesheets are hosted on the same domain your webpage is.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the failing line in a try-catch block. That's how i solved the same issue on one project.

Answer (score -2):

Try `window.document.styleSheets[x].cssRules.length` instead of `document.styleSheets[x].cssRules.length`. It will work on firefox without any security exception.