# Check if css property has !important attribute applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a style like this -

```
​div#testdiv {position:absolute;top:10px !important;}​
```

I can query the `top` value with jQuery like this -

```
$("#testdiv").css("top");
```

which will return the value `10px`. Is it possible to use jQuery or JavaScript to check if the  `top` property has had the `!important` attribute applied to it?

Comment: like this: div.style().getPropertyPriority('top')  ?   You may be interested in : http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/cssMisc.html  . Not a jQuery solution though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, such a solution does not seem to exist in jQuery.

Many available javascript solutions offered, use the function `getPropertyPriority()`. First, this function is not supported by IE6-IE8 ( see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#misc) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Second, this function does not directly work on elements if their style is not declared *inline*. So, we would be able to get the important property in the following case:

```
<div id="testdiv" style="top : 10px !important;">Some div</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// should show 'important' in the console.
console.log(document.getElementById("testdiv").style.getPropertyPriority('top'));
</script>
```

However if we could declare the style of `#testdiv` in a css stylesheet, we will get an empty string. Also the `CSSStyleDeclaration` interface is not available in IE6-8. Ofcourse this is pretty useless this way. We need a different approach.

I've put this approach into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCM3Z/). We can read the !important property directly from the css stylesheets, which are contained in the array `document.styleSheets[]`. (Opera 8 and below do not support this array). At [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#access) you can see the methods which methods are supported to access the stylesheets. Based on this information we can do the following:

- For IE6-8, we use the `styleSheets[].imports` to access the imported stylesheets (and keep doing this recursively till we do not find any import statements anymore) and then `styleSheets[].rules` basically for each stylesheet add the css rules to an array.
- For other browsers, we use `styleSheets[].cssRules` to access both the imported and css rules. We detect the import rules by checking if it implements the *CSSImportRule* interface and use these to access the css rules in the imported stylesheets recursively.

In both cases we add the css rules to an array only if the rules matches the HTMLElement (in your case `#testdiv`). This results in an array of css rules that are matched to a HTMLElement. This is basically what the `getMatchedCSSRules()` function in webkit browsers does. However, we write it ourselves here.

Based on this information we write our `hasImportant(htmlNode, property)` function, where htmlNode is an HTMLElement (your testdiv) and property the css property ('top' in your case). First, we check if the inline style of the top property has an important attribute. This saves us looking through the stylesheets if it does contain this attribute.

We write a new function `isImportant(node, property)` which uses our good old function `node.style.getPropertyPriority(property)`. However, like I mentioned earlier in this answer: this function is not supported in IE6-IE8. We can write the function ourselves: in IE the property `node.style.cssText` contains the declaration block text. We search for the property ('top') in this block of text and check if its value contains '!important'. We can reuse this function on every css rule obtained using the `getMatchedCSSRules` function, by looping through all css rules that match with the htmlNode and calling the isImportant function.

All of the above can be found in the code below. This is the basic approach and probably should be fine-tuned further:

- some code might be replaced with jQuery
- some code might be simplified
- css rules implementing the CSSMediaRule interface and [other interfaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet) might cause some problems for this code and an error check should be performed
- there might be simpler approach, but I am not aware of any other method to get this working cross browser.

  ```
  var debug = true;

  /**
   * Get the css rules of a stylesheet which apply to the htmlNode. Meaning its class
   * its id and its tag.
   * @param CSSStyleSheet styleSheet
   * @param HTMLElement htmlNode
   */
  function getCssRules(styleSheet, htmlNode) {
      if ( !styleSheet )
          return null;

      var cssRules = new Array();
      if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
          var currentCssRules = styleSheet.cssRules;
          // Import statement are always at the top of the css file.
          for ( var i = 0; i < currentCssRules.length; i++ ) {
              // cssRules all contains the import statements.
              // check if the rule is an import rule.
              if ( isImportRule(currentCssRules[i]) ) {
                  // import the rules from the imported css file.
                  var importCssRules = getCssRules(currentCssRules[i].styleSheet, htmlNode);
                  if ( importCssRules != null ) {
                      // Add the rules from the import css file to the list of css rules.
                      cssRules = addToArray(cssRules, importCssRules, htmlNode);
                  }
                  // Remove the import css rule from the css rules.
                  styleSheet.deleteRule(i);
              }
              else {
                  // We found a rule that is not an CSSImportRule
                  break;
              }
          }
          // After adding the import rules (lower priority than those in the current stylesheet),
          // add the rules in the current stylesheet.
          cssRules = addToArray(cssRules, currentCssRules, htmlNode);
      }
      else if (styleSheet.rules) {
          // IE6-8
          // rules do not contain the import statements.
          var currentCssRules = styleSheet.rules;

          // Handle the imports in a styleSheet file.
          if ( styleSheet.imports ) {
              // IE6-8 use a seperate array which contains the imported css files.
              var imports = styleSheet.imports;
              for ( var i = 0; i < imports.length; i++ ) {
                  var importCssRules = getCssRules(imports[i], htmlNode);
                  if ( importCssRules != null ) {
                      // Add the rules from the import css file to the list of css rules.
                      cssRules = addToArray(cssRules, importCssRules, htmlNode);
                  }
              }
          }
          // After adding the import rules (lower priority than those in the current stylesheet),
          // add the rules in the current stylesheet.
          cssRules = addToArray(cssRules, currentCssRules, htmlNode);
      }

      return cssRules;
  }

  /**
   * Since a list of rules is returned, we cannot use concat. 
   * Just use old good push....
   * @param CSSRuleList cssRules
   * @param CSSRuleList cssRules
   * @param HTMLElement htmlNode
   */
  function addToArray(cssRules, newRules, htmlNode) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < newRules.length; i++ ) {
          if ( htmlNode != undefined && htmlNode != null && isMatchCssRule(htmlNode, newRules[i]) )
              cssRules.push(newRules[i]);
      }
      return cssRules;
  }

  /**
   * Matches a htmlNode to a cssRule. If it matches, return true.
   * @param HTMLElement htmlNode
   * @param CSSRule cssRule
   */
  function isMatchCssRule(htmlNode, cssRule) {
      // Simply use jQuery here to see if there cssRule matches the htmlNode...
      return $(htmlNode).is(cssRule.selectorText);
  }

  /**
   * Verifies if the cssRule implements the interface of type CSSImportRule.
   * @param CSSRule cssRule
   */
  function isImportRule(cssRule) {
      return cssRule.constructor.toString().search("CSSImportRule") != -1;
  }

  /**
   * Webkit browsers contain this function, but other browsers do not (yet).
   * Implement it ourselves...
   *
   * Finds all matching CSS rules for the htmlNode.
   * @param HTMLElement htmlNode
   */
  function getMatchedCSSRules(htmlNode) {
      var cssRules = new Array();

      // Opera 8- don't support styleSheets[] array.
      if ( !document.styleSheets )
          return null;

      // Loop through the stylesheets in the html document.
      for ( var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++ ) {
          var currentCssRules = getCssRules(document.styleSheets[i], htmlNode)
          if ( currentCssRules != null )
              cssRules.push.apply(cssRules, currentCssRules);
      }

      return cssRules;
  }

  /**
   * Checks if the CSSStyleRule has the property with 'important' attribute.
   * @param CSSStyleRule node
   * @param String property
   */
  function isImportant(node, property) {
      if ( node.style.getPropertyPriority && node.style.getPropertyPriority(property) == 'important' )
          return true;
      else if ( node.style.cssText && getPropertyPriority(node.style.cssText, property) == 'important' ) {
          // IE6-8
          // IE thinks that cssText is part of rule.style
          return true;
      }
  }

  /**
   * getPropertyPriority function for IE6-8
   * @param String cssText
   * @param String property
   */
  function getPropertyPriority(cssText, property) {
      var props = cssText.split(";");
      for ( var i = 0; i < props.length; i++ ) {
          if ( props[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(property.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {
              // Found the correct property
              if ( props[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("!important") != -1 || props[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("! important") != -1) {
                  // IE automaticaly adds a space between ! and important...
                  return 'important'; // We found the important property for the property, return 'important'.
              }
          }
      }
      return ''; // We did not found the css property with important attribute.
  }

  /**
   * Outputs a debug message if debugging is enabled.
   * @param String msg
   */
  function debugMsg(msg) {
      if ( debug ) {
          // For debugging purposes.
          if ( window.console )
              console.log(msg);
          else
              alert(msg);
      }
  }

  /**
   * The main functionality required, to check whether a certain property of 
   * some html element has the important attribute.
   * 
   * @param HTMLElement htmlNode
   * @param String property
   */
  function hasImportant(htmlNode, property) {

      // First check inline style for important.
      if ( isImportant(htmlNode, property) ) {
          // For debugging purposes.
          debugMsg("Inline contains important!");
          return true;
      }

      var rules = getMatchedCSSRules(htmlNode);

      if ( rules == null ) {
          debugMsg("This browser does not support styleSheets...");
          return false;
      }

      /**
       * Iterate through the rules backwards, since rules are
       * ordered by priority where the highest priority is last.
       */
      for ( var i = rules.length; i-- > 0; ) {
          var rule = rules[i];

          if ( isImportant(rule, property) ) {
              // For debugging purposes.
              debugMsg("Css contains important!");
              return true;
          }

      }
      return false;
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
      hasImportant($('#testdiv')[0], 'top');
  });
  ```

Answer (score 6):

See [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/jquery-css-applying-important-styles/8894528#8894528)

There's a function there that you can add to jQuery. Then you use it like this:

`console.log($('#testdiv').style().getPropertyPriority('top'));`

Comment: This isn't working for me, see - http://jsfiddle.net/74MCx/. The function works if I set the CSS value via the function's set method but won't work with styles that are declared in CSS (a blank string is returned).

Comment: Like @dennisg says: it apparently only works for styles set inline on the element :( (i.e. <div id="testdiv" style="top: 10px !important">Hello</div>)

Answer (score 1):

you can try reading it directly from the css style sheet.

have a look at the second answer of this question:
[get CSS rule's percentage value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery)