# get background value using css in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/g6h28a2a/

```
div {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/tOaDddv.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```js
alert($('div').css('background'));
```

I expect it to return `url('http://i.imgur.com/tOaDddv.png') no-repeat;` but it returned a strange string. Although it worked too if I assign that value to another element but I just don't understand why it returned that strange string.

Comment: jQuery `css()` method returns the computed style which can be different from browser to browser

Comment: Inspect the element and view the computed styles: http://i.imgur.com/Z2frsPM.png

Answer (score 3):

'background' is a concatenation of properties (read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)). What I asume you want is the 'background-image' and 'background-repeat' properties.

```
alert($('div').css('background-image') + " " + $('div').css('background-repeat'));
```

Comment: Ya but what if as suggested by OP in other answer's comment there is an `!important` statement. In fact OP should look at `document.styleSheets` but i just don't see any reason for that

Comment: @A.Wolff: That functionality does not exist in jQuery. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314131/check-if-css-property-has-important-attribute-applied for a none jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

you colud combine two attributes to get the same what you need:

```
alert(
   $('div').css('background-image') 
   + ' ' 
   + $('div').css('background-repeat') 
 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```js
alert($('div').css('background-image'));
```

```css
div {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/tOaDddv.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: What about `no-repeat` statement?

Comment: UM, how is this ANY different than what the OP posted? You specified just the image? You do not explain why the OP sees what they see.

Comment: I think people downvoting it could at least leave a comment

Comment: This answer isolates the background url which is evidently what the OP wants to see. This works.

Comment: OP expects to see `url('http://i.imgur.com/tOaDddv.png') no-repeat;` not just the BG image. Question does not answer WHY

Comment: Seriously, the downvote bombs drive me crazy sometimes.

Comment: @ Akshay What the OP expect is `url('http://i.imgur.com/tOaDddv.png') no-repeat`.