# SecurityError when trying to get cssRules in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, securityexception

Simple `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` from console works fine. But when trying to get this from function:

```
var asd = function(){ return document.styleSheets[0].cssRules }
console.log( asd() );
```

causes:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

There was no problems with Chrome browser.

---

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18852892/3743145) I tried to set `crossorigin` attribute to "anonymous" and "use-credentials" with no success

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```