# I cannot get all the cssRules for some pages

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get all CSS rules by using JavaScript.
On some page I sucess, on some I don't success.

For example, here in StackOverflow, I am using:

```
console.log(
document.styleSheets[1].href,'rules',
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules,'Should be css rules, and not null'
)
```

This is what I get:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=f7d3e9ff74be rules null Should be css rules, and not null
```

For some other website it's works well, but sometimes not.

For example in github.com this is what I get:

```
https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github2/index-87247f16e6450ef54cb0eda3f8f1484e33a3f18c7a7d3df1f76f67cba36a8d6d.css CSSRuleList {0: CSSStyleRule, 1: CSSStyleRule, 2: CSSStyleRule, 3: CSSStyleRule, 4: CSSStyleRule, 5: CSSStyleRule, 6: CSSStyleRule, 7: CSSStyleRule, 8: CSSStyleRule, 9: CSSStyleRule, 10: CSSStyleRule, 11: CSSStyleRule, 12: CSSStyleRule, 13: CSSStyleRule, 14: CSSStyleRule, 15: CSSStyleRule, 16: CSSStyleRule, 17: CSSStyleRule, 18: CSSStyleRule, 19: CSSStyleRule, 20: CSSStyleRule, 21: CSSStyleRule, 22:
```

What Can I do?

[image: Console example on stackoverflow]

1. I thought maybe it is because content-type. but no. It is always text/css
2. I thought maybe it because CORS issue, but I didn't see that this is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a CORS issue? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678040/cssrules-rules-are-null-in-chrome

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18471848/560114

Comment: It is not CORS issue, after reading those questions, I understand that it is impossible from other domains (even if allow access-control)

Comment: Why don't you think it's CORS? `cdn.sstatic.net` is not the same domain as `stackoverflow.com`, so you can't access the styles.

Comment: It's very much not CORS. What output are you expecting? Are you expecting `null` to not be null? The element that you're trying to get the `href` of doesn't have an `href`, so it IS `null`.

Comment: I think we need a better example...the stackoverflow styles for `styleSheets[1]` aren't available because they're from a different domain. Can you give an example of this happening with stylesheets on the same domain, on a publicly accessible site (so we can test it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.styleSheets` contains`<style type="text/css"></style>` as well as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` so you will not get href from the first one. I would check if those styles are not blank as well, in case they have no cssRules.